# Azure search schema migrations

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-cognitive-search

What's the best way to migrate an Azure search schema in a release pipeline?

In the SQL world, I'd use something like DbUp. Is there anything similar for Azure search?
Or is there a different approach when the schema needs to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you are pushing content via the SDK or if you are pulling content from a supported content source using one of the pre-built indexers. Using the SDK you can add new properties to your model as explained in this post: [Update Azure search document schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49989590/update-azure-search-document-schema)

Note: Changes in your data model may require either an *update* or a *rebuild* of the index. For example, adding new properties only requires and update. But, if you change a setting like searchable, filterable or sortable you will need a rebuild. For details, see [How to rebuild an index in Azure Cognitive Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-reindex)

COMPATIBILITY PROBING VIA PUSH

My preferred solution is to use push indexing for everything. To test if the data model in the index is compatible, I create a sample item and submit to the index. If the model used in the index is incompatible, and error is thrown by the Azure Search SDK. I then delete the index and create it from scratch using my new model.

Here is a simplified method to test if any item is compatible with a named index:

```
public async Task<bool> TestItemAsync<T>(T item, string indexName)
{
    var isCompatible = false;
    var indexClient = _searchServiceClient.Indexes.GetClient(indexName);
    var indexActions = new List<IndexAction<T>> { IndexAction.MergeOrUpload((item)) };

    var batch = IndexBatch.New(indexActions);
    try
    {
        var unused = await indexClient.Documents.IndexAsync(batch);
        isCompatible = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        // ignored
    }

    return isCompatible;
}
```

And here is an example of how you might use it to probe your index for compatibility.

```
var item = new Product();
item.ID = 123;
item.Title = "Sample";
item.MyNewProperty = "Some value"
// ... 

var isCompatible = await TestItemAsync(item, indexName);
if (isCompatible)
{
    await DeleteItemAsync(item, indexName);
}
else 
{
    await DeleteIndexAsync<T>(indexName);
    await CreateIndexAsync<T>(indexName);
}
```

To actually verify the compatiblity, make sure you populate your item with some values. In this example I hard-coded some values for the sake of the example. In actual use I use a Mock framework that populates every property of my item with some random sample value, but I did not want to give the impression that a third-party component is required for this use-case.